# Python Asks and Trio modules don't work together

Tags: python, networking, python-trio

I'm new to both Trio and Asks so apologies if this is an obvious mistake.

From the docs of Trio and Asks, I thought the following code would work and allow me to asynchronously make a request

```py
import asks
import trio

async def test():
    a = await asks.get('https://example.com')

trio.run(test)
```

But instead it gives me many errors and concludes with `AttributeError: module 'trio' has no attribute 'MultiError'`

From the documentation I assumed that both libraries are compatible, but perhaps this is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trio.MultiError` has been removed in newer versions.

```
import asks
import trio
import asyncio

async def test():
    try:
        response = await asks.get('https://google.com')
        print("Response:", response)
        print("Response status code:", response.status_code)
        print("Response text:", response.text)
    except trio.Cancelled as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

trio.run(test)
```

[reference](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-core.html#task-cancellation-and-exceptions)

**UPDATE**

uninstall the previous version of `anyio` using this command `pip uninstall anyio`

then install the compatible version with trio `pip install anyio[trio]`

then run the script again, you will get an output like this:

```
Response: <Response 429 Too Many Requests>
Response status code: 429
Response text: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1"><title>https://google.com/</title></head>
<body style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; color: #000; padding:20px; font-size:18px; overscroll-behavior:contain;" onload="e=document.getElementById('captcha');if(e){e.focus();} if(solveSimpleChallenge) {solveSimpleChallenge(,);}">
<div style="max-width:400px;">
<hr noshade size="1" style="color:#ccc; background-color:#ccc;"><br>
<form id="captcha-form" action="index" method="post">
<noscript>
<div style="font-size:13px;">
  In order to continue, please enable javascript on your web browser.
</div>
</noscript>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<script>var submitCallback = function(response) {document.getElementById('captcha-form').submit();};</script>
<div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfwuyUTAAAAAOAmoS0fdqijC2PbbdH4kjq62Y1b" data-callback="submitCallback" data-s="_tgCT2yHQMDHpfdZ6VLDfvvGJTkL_TiVH-Nmf9UR0j5cBe60qBkNCjt2WVZsXz1wQQ90wfqcJ6VHBt8LCiCCCfpWawN0o2W0U1QUu_L_ho1fpCA_fmLbeTby5DMCYObVxdW2dzi_KlzKQ0lzhbo4_EVYh6IgAJ3NhlK67C4Q2gn_j47MWYHNZSF0JuPK4d7SctCVLBgr57uePxnZLHUMO2MPhQ5mKy5CZl3Rl8dHQUWbTQxXg0PKyo7-WTrX9avU22nvB0MfJWWRxzKfUL_POwXLrNhjpIA"></div>

<input type='hidden' name='q' value='EgSKxy_DGIrMla4GIjAYHTL1QYtmVFwVUix8upuZjQ3AuJv4FIXnA0sxrqy8hI0cJ2Hyiy4dK12v50Gm8zkyAXJKGVNPUlJZX0FCVVNJVkVfTkVUX01FU1NBR0VaAUM'><input type="hidden" name="continue" value="https://google.com/">
</form>
<hr noshade size="1" style="color:#ccc; background-color:#ccc;">

<div style="font-size:13px;">
<b>About this page</b><br><br>
This network is blocked due to unaddressed abuse complaints about malicious behavior. This page checks to see if it's really a human sending the requests and not a robot coming from this network. <br><br>
<div id="infoDiv" style="display:none; background-color:#eee; padding:10px; margin:0 0 15px 0; line-height:1.4em;">
This page appears when Google automatically detects requests coming from your computer network which appear to be in violation of the <a href="//www.google.com/policies/terms/">Terms of Service</a>. The block will expire shortly after those requests stop.  In the meantime, solving the above CAPTCHA will let you continue to use our services.<br><br>This traffic may have been sent by malicious software, a browser plug-in, or a script that sends automated requests.  If you share your network connection, ask your administrator for help &mdash; a different computer using the same IP address may be responsible.  <a href="//support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640">Learn more</a><br><br>Sometimes you may be asked to solve the CAPTCHA if you are using advanced terms that robots are known to use, or sending requests very quickly.
</div>

IP address: *.*.*.*<br>Time: 2024-02-08T23:38:51Z<br>URL: https://google.com/<br>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this catches the error but still fails to make the request successfully

Comment: Marvellous, thank you. Reinstalling `anyio` fixed the problem for me